# What's the name of this song from Episode 16 of Shingeki no Kyojin?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

If possible I'd like to know the YouTube link for this song. It plays during episode 16 of Shingeki no Kyojin when they receive their capes for joining the Survey Corps.

Comment: Note: for easier reference, the mentioned song is on minute 18:40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The song is called '**Call Your Name**', arranged and composed by Hiroyuki Sawano.
- Here's a link to the part that you mentioned, when they receive their capes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApU72YmOcY8
- This is an AMV of the song (which I have downloaded myself): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZ9kKyo40PY

I would recommend downloading an app called Shazam to help with identifying music and song lyrics

Hope this helps!